# How to select through several dynamic tables?

Tags: mysql

I use sereval tables to store files :

`files` contains informations about each file (id, date, extension ....)

`files2000` contains the content of all files dated in year 2000 (id_file, content)

`files2001` contains the content of all files dated in year 2001 (id_file, content)

`files2002` contains the content of all files dated in year 2002 (id_file, content)

etc .....

Question is : how can I do a request for searching a file on date, extension AND content ?
Thanks in advance !

Edit : Separated tables because only one table would be toooo heavy (more than 200 000 files ;))

Tables can be constructed like that :

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `extension` text NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `files` (`id`, `name`, `date`, `extension`) VALUES
(0, 'File_1', '2000-05-07', 'PDF'),
(1, 'File_2', '2000-11-01', 'ODT'),
(2, 'File_3', '2001-03-20', 'XLS'),
(3, 'File_4', '2001-04-28', 'TXT'),
(4, 'File_5', '2002-12-31', 'DOC');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files2000` (
  `id_file` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `content` blob NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_file` (`id_file`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `files2000` (`id_file`, `content`) VALUES
(1, 0x636f6e74656e7431),
(2, 0x636f6e74656e7432);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files2001` (
  `id_file` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `content` blob NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_file` (`id_file`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `files2001` (`id_file`, `content`) VALUES
(3, 0x636f6e74656e7433),
(4, 0x636f6e74656e7434);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files2002` (
  `id_file` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `content` blob NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_file` (`id_file`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `files2002` (`id_file`, `content`) VALUES
(5, 0x636f6e74656e7435);

Comment: Do you have any sample data and expected results? And who's idea was it to design a schema like *that*?

Comment: Why those separate tables per year?

Answer (score 0):

One, probably very slow query would be:

```
select
  f.*,
  c.content
from
    files f
    inner join 
       (select id_file, content from files2000 union all
        select id_file, content from files2001 union all
        ...
        select id_file, content from files2013 union all
        select id_file, content from files2014) c on c.id_file = f.id_file
where
    f.extension = 'exe' and
    f.date between ... and ... and
    c.content like '%search string%'
```

But you would have to update this query every year. You should really consider putting all the content in a single table, or if you did this for performance have one 'recent' table and one 'archive' table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , yes you're true, I do this for performance, and I can't really have 'archive' table for a lot of reasons. Content tables are created dynamically, and I have files from 1950 to 2015 .. So, the "inner join / union all" solution seems to be not suitable.

Comment: you can add the where clause with the search criteria into the select for each union. the performance will be a lot better, and if you generate the query, it will be still maintainable anyway.

Comment: If you generate the query, then yes. You could even leave out some of the year tables based on the startdate and enddate given.